# React - Redux | Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Everything is fine until login > dispatch > payload: err.response.data. Then gives an error: 
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
I've checked many sources but I can't find what is wrong.
In register, payload: err.response.data works perfectly. But
In login, gives this error

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER } from "./types";

// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Login - Get User Token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      // Set token to ls
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};

// Log user out
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  // Remove token from localStorage
  localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
};
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a console.log before the dispatch and have a look into err?

Comment: Hi @MarcelT. , i have tried console.log. It says undefined. But it can't go to the right way: "/dashboard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine, however I would try this:

1. Whenever you server launch the error, make sure you emit this object:

   `response.json({response: {data: "Error..."}})`
2. Otherwise check the undefined object in **loginUser** function:

   `payload: ((err||{}).response||{}).data || 'Error unexpected'`

   That will check your nested object before you have undefined values.

   Solution picked from [Oliver Steele  Blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20161108071447/http://blog.osteele.com/posts/2007/12/cheap-monads/)

Comment: Hi, object is undefined. I tried your 2. code. And development server does'nt start. Could there be a problem with React?

Comment: Hi, I think you might have another issue in react and this is why you sever doesn't  start. Post here the error if you have it!

Comment: Whoah! I fix it. I retry your 2. code. says: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `errors` of type `string` supplied to `Login`, expected `object`.
    in Login (created by Connect(Login))
    in Connect(Login) (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:28)
    in div (at App.js:23)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:22)
    in Provider (at App.js:21)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)

Comment: Congrats! But I didn't know you expected an object instead of a text as 'Error unexpected'. That's ok :)